# Why does this jquery not work?

Tags: jquery, find, addclass

```
$(function () {

    if($('body').find('#slideshow')) {
        $('body').find('.topBox').addClass('home');   
    }

});
```

I mean it works, but if i take out `#slideshow` it will still add the class?

I tried else remove class.

Comment: "Why does this jquery not work?" but "I mean it works" O_o

Comment: Describe the complete task you're trying to solve.

Comment: lol I didn't really explain what i was trying to do I assumed it was self explanetory. Basically I wanted: if the section slideshow was found, find div topbox and add a class to it, someone has already given me the solution, sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check the existence of an element then you can use [**`.length`**](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property for that element selector.

What about this code

```
if ($("#slideshow").length > 0)
{
    $('.topBox').addClass('home'); 
}
```

Comment: Bang on, I read somewhere before posting here something about length, but I just assumed it wasn't right lol. Nice one

Answer (score 1):

The return value from `jQuery('body').find(...)` will always be true as it returns a jQuery object.

You want to check if it returns any elements that match, so you want:

```
if(jQuery('body').find(...).size())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('body').find('#slideshow')) {}
```

will always evaluate as true. $('body').find('#slideshow') does return something: an object (even if its an empty object). Instead, test the length of the object:

```
if($('body').find('#slideshow').length) {}
```

Comment: Dang other people beat me. :-)